# Strange exception in MimeBodyPart.getContent()

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm using javamail 1.6.1 together with Apache TIKA (1.18) to parse email content as text. When I was using TIKA 1.17 it was working fine (some errors here and there, but 99% was working fine). When I'm switched to TIKA 1.18 something strange started to happen (in production environment) , I started to get (in masses) this exception:

```
IllegalArgumentException: failed to parse:
 at java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to parse:
 at java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor.<init>(DataFlavor.java:435)
 at javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor.<init>(ActivationDataFlavor.java:81)
```

When I tried to reproduce this issue on my local workstation, it was not reproducible. Switching back to TIKA 1.17 solved that issue.
I know that's it sounds very strange but any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The error message is supposed to include the MIME type that it fails to parse.  In this case it seems to be the empty string, which is definitely not a valid MIME type.  That probably means you're dealing with an email message that has a Content-Type header with no value.  How are you reading the message?  From an IMAP server?  POP3 server?  Local file?  We would need to see the details of the bad email message to know exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: The message was retrieved as Mime content from Exchange Web Service. So it's actually local file and read into java MimeMessage.

Comment: Can you post a sample message that shows this problem?  Since the message is corrupt, you'll need to catch the exception and handle the content differently, e.g., by using the getInputStream method.

Comment: Hi Bill, the problem is that I can't reproduce, means I see many emails fail on that problem , but when I'm trying to take some of them it's works fine. Also, messages seems to be not corrupted, as when I'm read them from local disk and build MimeMessage from them , the MimeMessage created ok. I know that it's soudns very strange, as I can't put finger os something specific. But all works fine when I reverted TIKA to 1.17 and if I switch back to 1.18 then problems will start again. Thanks

Comment: If you can capture the local file when this fails, that would be helpful.  I know nothing about TIKA but hopefully it's not modifying the message before you see it.  In any event, you should probably be catching the exception so you can recover from the failure.

Comment: Thanks Bill, so far no luck with catching this and reproduce it. Our dev team is working now to catch. The issue is still not reproducible, it's happens in the production all the time, but when I'm trying to parse again emails that caused that exception on local workstation or even in production - it's passes fine, and then another mail from another customer fails.

Comment: That's pretty weird.  If you track it down to a JavaMail bug, let me know, but it looks like you might need to dig into TIKA to find out what it's doing with the messages.